# Using variables to create instance of class

Tags: python, tkinter

For this program it is needed to select different classes dependent on the users input. In short how the program works:

1. User selects Square or triangle
2. Dependend on type of shape desired the input form changes
3. At `OnButtonAddNew` the shape is added to the `element`

Since all the shapes require the same amount of variables (or i let some var empty) it should be possible to add the new element to the list of elements using variables. The way I tried it now with `self.x` isn't working out. I also tried to use `getattr` but this was also not working out for me.

```
import tkinter as tk

element = [] # stores list of objects

class mainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        'Input of values'
        tk.Label(self, text='y').grid(column=2, row=16, sticky=tk.W)
        self.y = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.entryY = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.y)
        self.entryY.grid(column=3, row=16, sticky='EW')
        'Drowdown menu'
        self.options = ['Square', 'Triangle'] # multiple types of classes
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.var.set(self.options[0])
        self.DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.var, *self.options, command=self.initForm)
        self.DropDown.grid(column=3, row=5)
        'Button add new object'
        self.buttonSet = tk.Button(self, text='Set', width=12, command=self.OnButtonAddNewClick)
        self.buttonSet.grid(column=2, row=30)

        self.update()

    def initForm(self, event):
        self.x = self.var.get() # get selected type of class

    def OnButtonAddNewClick(self):
        global element
        new_element = self.x(self.y.get(), len(element)) # create new instance of class and add it to the elements
        element = np.append(element, new_element)


class Square:
    def __init__(self, y0, elementNumber):
        self.y0 = y0
        print('Added new instance square, y0:', self.y0)


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, y0, elementNumber):
        self.y0 = y0
        print('Added new instance triangle, y0:', self.y0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    mainWindow(root).pack(side='top', fill='both')
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, please post it as an answer, not edit to the question. It is fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this is by using `globals()`:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print('Added new instance square, y0:', self.x)

def call(str):
    obj = globals()[str](4)
    return obj

c = call('C')
print(c.x)
```